# Batch conversion of polygonz into polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, batch, kmz

I have a bunch of kmz files which I need to merge into one so I can convert it into one polygon shapefile using QGIS.

The problem is that I have some kmz that are polygon, and some that are polygonz and QGIS wont allow the merging of different types of geometry.

So, how can I convert all those polygonz at once (batch) into polygon? (without the z attribute)?

(I know I can save one by one as shapefile than change the geometry type, but I wonder if there is a faster way since I have many layers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you could run an ogr2ogr script (after extracting the kmz to kml first, this can be done with any unzip tool) to convert all the files to ShapeFile:

`for /R %f in (*.kml) do ogr2ogr "%~dpnf.shp" -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI "%f"`

Answer (score 3):

For instance, you could use the SAGA "Flatten polygon layer" tool from Processing executing it as a batch process.