# QGIS Batch vector layer $ shapefile $ polygon processing

Tags: qgis, batch

I am wondering how to make the batch vector layer setup for my comma-delimited layers inputted.

In the image below there is one layer ready (merged with few layers) and few other comma-delimited layers, which appear to be looking the same as the first one.

[image]

For the first one I done:

1. Minimum bounding geometry - convex hull
2. Make buffers
3. Merging them into one piece
4. Customizing the styles by categorized

I would like to do pretty much the same for the remaining ones. Is there a possibility to do these steps for all of them at once (batch process)?

I see, that some batch processing in QGIS is possible:

[Extracting polygons by attribute in batch processing using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290846/extracting-polygons-by-attribute-in-batch-processing-using-pyqgis)
[Batch conversion of polygonz into polygon in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263294/batch-conversion-of-polygonz-into-polygon-in-qgis/263298#263298)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a graphical model containing your processing steps and run this model as batch.

1. Create a graphical model

[image]

[image]

2. Open the model and click on "Run as batch process"

[image]

3. Fill the parameters and run the model

[image]